# MotionEvent is recycled while still in use

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, touch-event, motionevent

I'm using a `SurfaceView` to draw touches as an overlay over my app. I would like my other `View`s to be able to respond to touch events while at the same time as the `SurfaceView` so in the `ViewGroup` that contains them both I added

MyViewGroup:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    mSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return false;
}
```

Since the `SurfaceView` sits behind the other views, this works great. Both the `SurfaceView` and the `View` on top of it receive the `MotionEvent`.

The `SurfaceView` then further forwards the event to the thread rendering into it.

MySurfaceView:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (mThreadHandler != null){
        mThreadHandler.sendMotionEvent(motionEvent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then when my rendering thread receives the message it runs:

MyRenderThread:

```
private void handleMotionEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float x = motionEvent.getX();                          // Breakpoint 1
            float x2 = motionEvent.getX();                         // Breakpoint 2
            float x3 = motionEvent.getX();                         // Breakpoint 3
            path.moveTo(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // do nothing
            break;
        default:
            break;
   }
}
```

When I run this code in debug mode and swipe my finger across the `ViewGroup` the values for `x`, `x2`, and `x3` all differ. I suspect this is because the UI thread is re-using the MotionEvent before it has been consumed by `MyRenderThread`. How can I fix this?

The bad solution would be to copy each `MotionEvent` as a new object and pass that to `MyRenderThread`, but this requires *a lot* of object creation/destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MotionEvent.obtain(MotionEvent ev)` will return a `MotionEvent` from the pool that is a copy of the input event.

MyViewGroup:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    mSurfaceView.fowardTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent); 
    return false;
}
```

MySurfaceView:

```
public void forwardTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    if (scratchpadThreadHandler != null){
        scratchpadThreadHandler.sendMotionEvent(motionEvent);
    }
}
```

MyRenderThread:

```
private void handleMotionEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float x = motionEvent.getX();                          // Breakpoint 1
            float x2 = motionEvent.getX();                         // Breakpoint 2
            float x3 = motionEvent.getX();                         // Breakpoint 3
            path.moveTo(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // do nothing
            break;
        default:
            break;
   }
    motionEvent.recycle();  // Mark this MotionEvent as available for recycling.
}
```

This way each event is still copied (not sure what to do about that) but at least the objects are reused.